# Trying to implement Z Table lookup in code

Tags: math.net

I'm taking a manual process and recreating it in a C# program. My process calculates a value, for example .32. In the manual process I'd go to a table like https://www.ztable.net and pull in the value 0.6225. I'm having trouble recreating this z table lookup in code. Is there a function in Math.Net that I could use to return these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// required declaration 
using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;

// usage
var r = Normal.CDF(0.0,1.0,0.32); // mean,standard deviation, x-value

// returns r = 0.62551834...
```